# Linting Python: what is good?

Tags: python, pylint

Are there any good modules that you can run against your code to catch coding errors? I expected pylint to catch mistakes in the use of default arguments to functions [like this](http://www.deadlybloodyserious.com/2008/05/default-argument-blunders/):

```
>>> def spam(eggs=[]):
...     eggs.append("spam")
...     return eggs
```

but was disappointed to find them unreported. I am looking for something beyond PEP8 formatting.

Comment: What's wrong with unit tests?

Comment: You accidentally used the correct version of the second function.

Comment: knowing just the signature of this function (`spam(eggs)`), this does exactly what I expect, that is, returning an every increasing amount of spam.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried the first example and PyLint 0.18.1 gave me the warning:

```
W:  1:spam: Dangerous default value [] as argument
```

Comment: Actually, I linted someone's code after I noted this code error. Then I pylint'd the code. In between, he changed the code and I did not notice it. So -- operator error. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

That is not an error in your code if that is what you want to do. However, as specified in the accepted answer, an empty list is a "dangerous" default value in that it is easy to introduce hard-to-find problems.

Comment: No, I really didn't want to do that. I wanted pylint to detect it -- and it did. Unfortunately, the codebase changed between when I detected the problem visually and when I ran pylint on the unbeknownst-to-me corrected code. See? It was working and I didn't realize it.